# how to write a junit test case for a toString() method

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, tdd

very need to tdd, junit, testing etc.

how can I test this?

```
public String toString()
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append(SalesExceptionHandlerImpl.class.getName() + " [");
        builder.append("toString()=");
        builder.append(super.toString());
        builder.append(", getClass()=");
        builder.append(getClass());
        builder.append(", hashCode()=");
        builder.append(hashCode());
        builder.append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }
```

code attempted:

```
public class RMSalesExceptionHandlerImplTest {

    @Test
    public void toStringReturnAnEmptyString(){
        SalesExceptionHandlerImpl salesExceptionHandlerImpl = new SalesExceptionHandlerImpl();
        assert.areEqual(salesExceptionHandlerImpl.toString(), "");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are late to the party. With TDD you first write unit test then follow with implementation. You already have implementation but no test is present. You can write missing unit test (that would be perfectly fine) or you can forget about your current implementation and try **test-first** approach (like TDD).

In test first you start with very simple test first. For `toString()` method it might be something like (using [JUnit for assertions](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html)):

```
public void toString_returnsEmptyString()
{
    SomeClass classUnderTest = new SomeClass();

    assertEquals(classUnderTest.toString(), "");
}
```

Why would you even need such test in first place? It might seem silly but it's here to ensure you can create your testing environment (`SomeClass` instance) without problems. This is rather important as you want to avoid any distractions when dealing with more complex tests and more complex problems.

Once it is established that you can create your object and you can return some string you can add more tests. Like:

```
public void toString_returnsStringWithSuperClassToStringEmbedded()
{
    SomeClass classUnderTest = new SomeClass();

    assertThat(classUnderTest.toString(), contains("This is super's toString"));
}
```

You then add appropriate implementation.

Next step would be to stop writing tests and check whether you can refactor anything (following [Red-Green-Refactor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development#Development_style) mantra). At this stage, most likely not. Which means you add more tests (getClass, hashCode, formatting, etc). Rinse & repeat until you reach a point where you are happy with both your tests and implementation.

Eventually, you end up with bunch of tests. Maybe some of them are superfluous and you have to delete them (like the very first test you wrote). Maybe some of them can be merged into single test. Maybe you simply need one test that verifies that produced string is in the exact shape as you expect. But that's what TDD is -- your tests and implementation will usually evolve heavily until they reach a form that is best suiting your requirements.

Comment: hello. this seems very helpful and I will mark it as correct if you can help me out with this. the code i have gone with is in my question as edited. 

but 'assert.areEqual' is underlined in red saying the method is undefined for the type RMSalesExceptionHandlerImpl  (name of my class). any ideas?

Comment: @BlackMagma: it should be [assertEquals](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html), assuming you use JUnit. Fixed code samples.

Comment: FYI assertNotNull worked best in this case. assertEquals failed. thanks for your help though

Answer (score 3):

If you know the result of your method, you don't care the implementation about it. 
If your function is a toString, you must simply test the result of your function.

```
public void testToString() {
    String result = "myResultThatIMustObtain";
    assertEquals(myInstance.toString(), result);

}
```